# convert calendarDuration to duration

Tags: matlab, datetime

Here's something that doesn't make sense to me:

```
caldays(1); %I get here by running this: between(datetime, datetime+days(1))
%ans = 
%
%  calendarDuration
%
%   1d

time(caldays(1))
%ans = 
%
%  duration
%
%   00:00:00
```

how can I actually convert calendarDurations to durations while preserving days, months and years? I couldn't find this on Mathworks help.

the purpose would be to compare if a certain number of minutes has already passed since a start-date.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `duration` instead of a `calendarDuration`, you can directly use:

```
duration = days(1)
```

To check if a certain amount of minutes have passed since a `start_date`:

```
now = datetime
is_5_minutes_passed = (now - start_date) >= minutes(5)
```

**Update:**

```
[d,t] = split(calendarDuration, {'days','time'})
duration = days(d) + t
```

Now you have a `duration` array.

Comment: I don't want to use the former because caldays(1) is the output of between(), I wrote this for simplification

Comment: you can convert a `calendarDuration` into a `duration`with `duration = days(caldays(calendar_duration))` Does it help?

Comment: if it worked that would help. but `days(caldays(1))` throws me a `Error using days (line 22)
Input data must be a real, numeric array.`

Comment: you should not apply directy `days` on `caldays(1)` but on `caldays(caldays(1))` If you apply again `caldays` on `caldays(1)` it gives you a variable on which you can call `days` to get a `duration`.  So the whole pipe is `cal_duration = caldays(1)` and then `duration = days(caldays(cal_duration))`. Is it a bit clearer?

Comment: ok that works, but if my calendarduration is only minutes and hours (less than a day) that is being cut-off

Comment: ok, so another option would be to split your `calendarDuration` like that: `[d,t] = split(calendarDuration, {'days','time'})` Then you can have durations not truncated with `duration = days(d) + t`

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I'll mark this as answer if there's really no way to 'just convert' the thing properly in one line of code

Comment: I couldn't get around the problem really, I used `between()` in my original code, it has a parameter to output days/hours etc, which is what I will use, but the problem sort of remains for me...